Has the moderator's several rewrites of my question gone a little bit too far, and actually convert it into a conspiracy theory question I didn't ask?
Soon after I posted a question with the title "Why was the gunboat USS Panay in China’s Yangtze River circa 1933?" and within the body:

I'm curious why exactly it was there in 1933. I understand there was a conflict between the Communists and Nationalists in China and yet at times they formed an alliance against Japanese invasions in this decade, but who (if anybody) actually invited the US Navy, and who first advised the US presidentthat the Navy should have a presence in the Yangtze River circa 1933?

A comment was posted linking to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yangtze_Patrol
I could have deleted the question, but instead I commented:

"The Yangtze Patrol also patrolled the coastal waters of China where they protected U.S. citizens, their property, and Christian missionaries." well this invalidates a lot of the wording of my question (e.g. "which president") and it raises a different question; was the main reason for the naval presence really to protect US citizens, their property, and missionaries? I guess I'll leave the question here as written, but obviously the answer will have to refute some of the implicit premises.

Of course, I was wise enough NOT to rewrite it as the "different question" those things raised, specifically because it would not have been a good Stack Exchange quesiton. I've asked literally thousands of them and it was clear that was not askable.
I did not delete the post either, because I

Didn't know if answers were already being written.
Answers would likely be interesting and add to the site.

At least that was my thinking, and I would consieer it a good-faith approach.
Unfortunately two poorly-received answers were posted by users with significant site reputation that seemed to use the opportunity to write unrelated material.
What bothers me is the way a series of edits by a moderator has ultimately converted the question into something totally different and what looks like a "conspiracy theory" quesiton, then the same modarator left the perlexing comment:

I don't like "was X really for reason Y" questions - they read like clickbait or like conspiracy theory. What leads you to question the narrative?

I do not believe that that comment applies to my original question - the one I wrote. I just wanted to know why it was there in 1933.
I also don't think that the way the moderator reposted my comment  within the question itself in gratuitously giant font, as if they'd caught a criminal in the act and were publicly shaming them is particularly helpful or appropriate:



Question: Has the moderator's several rewrites of my question gone a little bit too far, and actually convert it into a conspiracy theory question I didn't ask?
This feels more like activist moderation than "light touch" moderation. I can't roll-back or vote to un-accept the edits because they were made by a moderator and it would be perceied as an edit war, but the mod's comment feels almost disingenuous.
At a minimum, perhaps at only 2.1 questions per day, there's just a lot of extra time in need of something to do? But another way to think of this might be to question why there are only 2.1 questions per day.

For the record, I replied to the "I don't like..." comment with the following:

you've edited my quesiton several times, so severely that I don't even recognize it. Then you're questioning the thinking behind what is essentially now your question, not mine. I don't like that! I simply asked why it was there in 1933. I explained that I could not think of a particular reason in 1933 and was curious. You've introduced a giant boldfaced quote and then changed the title to question that quote. You've convertred the post into a conspiracy theory-type question. What ever happened to "light touch" in moderation?
I asked "I'm curious why exactly it was there in 1933. I understand there was a conflict between the Communists and Nationalists in China and yet at times they formed an alliance against Japanese invasions in this decade, but who (if anybody) actually invited the US Navy, and who first advised the US president that the Navy should have a presence in the Yangtze River circa 1933?" because I just wanted to know.


I didn't edit or comment on this post, so perhaps I can look at this a little dispassionately.
From the wording of this meta question I was expecting to click that question edit history and see 3 or more moderator edits, and a complete rewrite of the question text. That would certainly be worthy of complaint! However, that's not at all what I'm seeing.
Instead I found only 2 edits. The usual definition of "several" is 3 or more. So just to start off, the title of this meta question is factually incorrect.
One edit only changed the title. Roughly half of the changes IMHO clarified it. Information that could be looked up (like what type of boat the USS Pinnay was, and what country the Yangtze was in) was removed. That's fine. However, it did also change the question from a "Why" question to a "Yes or no" question, and added a proposition. That alone probably does qualify as a title "rewrite", and IMHO if the question author doesn't want to ask that question, its reasonable for them to change the edited title again to pose a question that they do want asked.
Where things really get interesting is that the OQ themselves down in the comments actually said this exact rewrite needed to be made!

This invalidates a lot of the wording of my question (e.g. "which
president") and it raises a different question; was the main reason
for the naval presence really to protect US citizens, their
property, and missionaries?

So this small title rewrite wasn't in fact the editor's invention, but rather OQ's.
Now to be fair, OQ did go on to say they didn't want to make the edit, and hoped answers would simply bring up the problem, and then answer the question that should have been asked. But the problem here is that simply won't work. The question will get closed if the question that was asked is trivially answerable, and nobody can answer a closed question. So without the edit, there's essentially no question!
The other edit was in fact an edit in the body, but not a word in there was modified or removed. Instead a new section was added addressing some of the comments. The added words were in fact the author's own words from down in the comments, with a quote from another comment added for context.
I do not find this edit to be a "rewrite" in any sense. It could be fairly argued that this bolt-on doesn't meld well with the rest of the question. That's a different argument, but I think it would be much fairer.
However, addressing comments by editing the question rather than (or in addition to) merely addressing them in comments is what question authors are supposed to do. If that isn't done, then other users who feel like the question might be salvageable might step in and do it themselves in an attempt to avoid the question being closed. This is actually an act of generosity on their part, which of course would not need to happen if the original author of the question had done it themselves. We really do want to have answerable questions here.
In fact, the edit comment says pretty much the same thing, if we stop to read it:

OP comments should be edited into the question; OP comments diminish
the probability of an answer and increase the probability of closure.

So what do I actually see here?

A single edit rewriting the title, harmonizing with the question the OQ thought could be answered in the comments. Don't like it? Fix it!
Another single edit tacking on the OQ's own answer to a comment.

So I don't find any of the charges in this meta question to have much merit, and in fact the moderator was doing a lot of extra work in a friendly attempt to save the question, entirely in harmony with what the OQ said in their own words they wanted answered.

"...said this exact rewrite needed to be made!" It does not say that at all. It says it raises another question, not that that question should be asked in a Stack Exchange post, nor that an edit should be made to the current post. A question is not the same as a Stack Exchange question post. Had I thought it should be asked in a question post, I would have asked it in a question post. Since it obviously shouldn't, I didn't. Why not simply suggest the change to me, rather than implement it in giant font, then change the tile, then complain about the title?

Having asked (yes) several thousand questions across a wide range of SE sites, I can say that what moderators will generally do is ask a question or make a suggestion first, to understand the OPs intent, for example "uhoh, if that's the question you want to ask, then consider going ahead and re-rewriting your question that way". This would allow me to respond that that would not be a good question.

@uhoh - That's the way I read it. If that's not what you meant to say there, I'm sorry. However, since I read it that way, I can't really fault someone else for misreading it that way as well.

Doesn't "it raises a different question" mean simply that it raises a different question? And doesn't me not changing the question (while there were still no answers) show that I didn't want to change the question and ask something else? I have to believe you read it differently, but I can't figure out how. Anyway, most moderators communicate directly with the post authors in a nice way, rather than make edits then complain about the result. I don't recall ever seeing this happen before.

@uhoh - Ahh, but changing the question to a different question was going to be required to keep it open at all, since the original was trivially answered. Its pretty natural to assume that finding a way to change it to keep it open is the goal of comments on a question in danger of closing.


How does moving my specific comment, unedited, into the post in giant bold font help keep the question post open, 2) why is keeping a problematic question post open even a good thing, even after the OP votes to close and comments that they've done so, 3) and why then complain in comments that it looks like a conspiracy theory question, which would seem to encourage other users seeing it in review to keep it closed (if a reopen process has started), and 4) why not just ask the OP what they want and/or need first?


just fyi this answer to What does “a couple” mean to you, and what does “a few” mean to you? contains a nice plot (on a log scale). Here's the source The single black dot at 2 for "several" here https://i.sstatic.net/5wVI88HO.png indicates that only one person out of their (presumably large) sample said 2. I assume that the dot being black indicates that it was flagged as an outlier and not included in the final analysis. There we have it - what I've suspected all along. I'm an outlier!

I think you're justified to be concerned and it was a mistake for the moderator to rewrite the question in a way that asks something quite different.  The original question was fine as a question,  just very simple to answer with a sentence or two and a wikipedia reference, should have been left at that in my opinion.
